# Ошибка при установке Android Studio

Tags: установка, android-studio

Добрый день! Подскажите!

При открытии Setup wizard выскакивает сообщение:

> The following SDK components were not
> installed: build-tools-21.1.1,
> source-21,sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21,
> extra-android-m2repository,
> android-21, extra-google-m2repository,
> addon-google_apis-google-21, tools,
> platform-tools          Retry   Cancel

Comment: @grigori, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: **Если ничего не помогает самый быстрый ,качественный ,гарантированный способ это переустановка Windows потом и android studio**

Answer (score 1):

1. Пользователь с правами администратора?
   Попробуйте запустить как админ.
2. В имени пользователя есть кириллица?
   Если есть, выберите другую папку для установки SDK (весь путь латиницей).
3. Попробуйте [установить](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/sdk/index.html) SDK и Studio по отдельности.

Comment: Спасибо! Совет помог :) исключил латиницу и все сработало.